# How do I give more disk space to my / and /home?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

This is possibly a duplicate question, but I haven't seen it answered for a case like mine.
On sda1, sda2, sda3 I have my old windows copy that I'm not using, so I would like to free up this space, split it equally in half, and redistribute it to my root (sda5) and home (sda7). How do I go about doing that?

[Gparted pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfUmc.png)

Much obliged.

Comment: The free space needs to be adjacent to whichever partition you want to expand, and because your Ubuntu installation is on an *extended* partition it might not be possible at all.  Is your hard drive partitioned with a MBR partition scheme for some reason?  It's more rigid than the newer GPT. You may need to reinstall the OS using a modern partition scheme and skip the "extended" partitions

Comment: @C.S.Cameron That's exactly what my comment says...  The screenshot clearly shows an extended partition and MBR partition scheme (msdos)

Answer (score 0):

### Removing Windows and Reallocating it's Partition Space

**Caution:** I have tested this with a persistent drive with extended partition, but not with a full install drive.

- Backup sda
- Boot Live USB and open GParted and unmount sda partitions
- Right click sda2 and `Delete`
- Right click sda3 and `Delete`
- Click `Apply All Operations`
- Right click sda5 and `Copy`
- Right click free space and `Paste`. Expand partition leaving room for sda7
- Click `Apply All Operations`
- Right click sda7 and `Copy`
- Right click free space and `Paste`
- Click `Apply All Operations`
- Delete everything inside sda4 and then `delete` sda4
- Click `Apply All Operations`
- `Resize/Move` the new partitions leaving room for a new swap partition.
- Click `Apply All Operations`

There should be no need to edit fstab as new partitions will have same UUID as old.

If necessary reinstall grub, I did not need to.

Comment: Are you sure this answer will work considering that the current drive is formatted with a MBR partition scheme?  Would this not exceed the partition limit?

Comment: @Nmath: The OP is removing Windows so sda2 and sda3 are deleted that leaves sda1, sda5-clone, sda6-new and sda7-clone. 4 partitions are allowed. I ran a simulation with this number of primary partitions and an extended partition before posting my answer.

Comment: Thank you both. I will instead just transfer my linux system onto a new drive since I'm in need of one anyway. That should be a fairly straightforward process, right? Just create three partitions there, and transfer sda5, 6, and 7 accordingly, with sda6 needing the least space?

Comment: @Blitva In that case, I would suggest that you format (erase) the entire drive as GPT, then reinstall Ubuntu onto empty space (booting UEFI mode from installation media). The installer will create necessary partitions.  If you still want `/home` separate, you can do that too.  What you're describing is not often successful and since you're getting a new disk you may as well as it up right from the start.

Comment: @Blitva If you transfer your Ubuntu partitions to a new drive you will need to **reinstall GRUB**. As an alternative you can clone your /home partition to the GPT formatted new drive using GParted, dd, or Disks. then you can make a fresh install using `something else`, select the old /home as the new /home **without** checking `Format`. After the install you can reinstall your old programs. You might have some complications cloning from MSDOS table to GPT.

Answer (score 0):

**Using FSArchiver and SuperGrub2 Backup and Restoration.**

You need an external drive to keep a backup and two USB sticks or CDs.

Create [SystemRescueCD](https://www.system-rescue.org/) or USB stick and boot outside of the drive.
`fsarchiver savefs /externaldrive/filename.fsa /dev/sda5 /dev/sda7`

Then you erase entire drive and create a new partition table and 2 or 3 partitions.
`fsarchiver restfs /externaldrive/filename.fsa id=0,dest=/dev/sda1 id=1,dest=/dev/sda2`

Grub is broken at this point and use [SuperGrub2](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) disk to restore grub.

---

Note: I am not sure if you can move the Linux partition to the beginning, but I am sure I couldn't do it not a long time ago, a few years ago. Since then I have never tried that again. Well, worth giving it a try, tools are getting wiser day by day.

Answer (score 0):

Radical

BACKUP all data, /etc and use synaptic to save all installed packages list.

FRESH install of 20.04.1 on the whole disc (partitions for root, boot and efi as you see fit {boot needs >>3x kernel/linux space*})
Use synaptic list to reinstall packages
*cough* uninstall snapd *cough* YMMV

*mine was as per internet (approx 2x) and now too small and struggling with upgrades, chrooting soon... before any other comments